# C# Selenium JavaScriptExecutor can't set or select option

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="k-list-scroller" unselectable="on" style="height: auto;">
    <ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="AdmittedFromId_listbox" aria-live="off" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox">
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="0">Physician/Hm w/o HH</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Ad Fr Hospital</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Ad fr SNF</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="3">Admit fr OthFacility</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="4">Ad Court Ordered</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
IWebElement admittedFrom = Driver.ngInstance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='AdmittedFromId']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor admittedFromExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.ngInstance;
admittedFromExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", admittedFrom);
admittedFromExecutor.ExecuteScript("document.getElementByID('AdmittedFromId_listbox').data-offset-index='1';");
```

```
IWebElement admittedFrom = Driver.ngInstance.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='AdmittedFromId']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor admittedFromExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.ngInstance;
admittedFromExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", admittedFrom);
admittedFromExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-offset-index',arguments[1])", admittedFrom, "1");
```

I've tried several more things but I can't set the value no matter what I try.
Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to _several more things_ I don't see you using the proven and powerful `Click()` but only `ExecuteScript()` even though you are using **`C#`**. Do you see any error as such?

Comment: Moreover, `id='AdmittedFromId'` is within `<ul>` tag, why would you use `By.XPath("//input[@id='AdmittedFromId']")`

Comment: I used click here:  admittedFromExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", admittedFrom);

Comment: That is a JavaScript click which should have been your last resort.

Comment: It has been my last resort.  I can't get selenium to see this dropdown to do anything with it.  I'm trying to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the id you are using for your findElement ("AdmittedFromId") does not match the one from your HTML ("AdmittedFromId_listbox").